# Outputing a sortable list from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I need the top 10 products sorted by total sales from a pandas dataframe. I can output a list with all the values and product name but cannot find a way of outputting a list of sorted values. I have tried creating lists, tuples and dictionaries but I keep getting an error that these cannot be sorted.

```
petproducts = df_cleaned['prod_title'].unique()

for x in petproducts:
  totaltoys =df_cleaned.loc[df_cleaned['prod_title'] == x, 'total_sales'].sum()
  print (x,totaltoys)
```

This gives me a series on pairs which I need to make into something where I can extract the top 10 products.I am a beginner I have been working on this for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `groupby` + `sum` to calculate total sales per `prod_title`, then use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) to get the top 10 products with highest sales

```
top10 = df_cleaned.groupby('prod_title')['total_sales'].sum().nlargest(10)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help it worked much simpler than iteration etc. I really need to learn groupby etc. Thanks again I very happy now.

Comment: @AndrewNewton Happy coding. If this answers your question, you may accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow. Accepted your answer thanks